# How to access arcgis map via components?

Tags: reactjs, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

The code below is taken directly from arcgis via react on how to display a map.

If i wanted to say, zoom in to a set of coordinates, but the code for that was set in another component, how can i get that component to talk to the map here in this component?

```
import Map from '@arcgis/core/Map';
import MapView from '@arcgis/core/views/MapView';

const map = new Map({
  basemap: "topo-vector"
});

const view = new MapView({
  container: "viewDiv",
  map: map
});
```

Comment: Check this [post from ESRI](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/js-api-arcgis/announcements/arcgis-api-for-javascript-working-with-frameworks-and-build-tools-just-got-easier-part-2/), and also [this repo](https://github.com/Esri/jsapi-resources/tree/master/esm-samples/jsapi-create-react-app) with a react example, it will probably help you.

Comment: @cabesuon unfortunately that post just shows how to create a simple map in a React app, but not how to control the map from outside of its component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by using redux toolkit to set the map as a global state object.

1. The entire map view is set in a useEffect, once i initialize each of the views, i dispatch the map view to a reducer in rtk.

```
    dispatch(updateMapViewState(view));

    updateMapViewState: (state, action) => {
      state.view = action.payload
    },
```

Then, when i want to use the map in a separate component, i do:

```
    const view = useSelector((state) => state.MapSlice.view);
```

In this way, all components can access the map outside of the useEffect in the map component, and can manipulate it without creating a new map view. This worked for me. I assume you could probably do this with context api, but we aren't using that as a global state manager.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the recommended or best way to achieve this, but I had success by passing the `view` object from the map component back to the parent component, then saving it to the parent component's state.

```
// in App.js
saveViewToState(view){
  this.setState({view: view})
}

<MapComponent saveViewToState={this.saveViewToState}/>

// in MapComponent.js
let view = new View()
this.props.saveViewToState(view)
```

Then I was able to interact with the `view` object from the parent:

```
// in App.js
this.state.view.extent = {xmin: 1, ymin: 1, xmax: 2, ymax: 2}
```

This doesn't work perfectly (for some reason I can't call `view.goTo`, but `view.extent` works). I'd be keen to hear if there is a better way to achieve this.

Comment: I used redux toolkit for this, and set the map as a state value, that I can pass between components, so im always using the same loaded map data

Comment: @JoshWinters that sounds promising. Can you add this as an answer, with more details?

Answer (score 0):

Still looking for a clear answer to this problem.
Have not found an example separating the map/view creation and adding layers into differing components.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33292789)